# Bash Script to Copy a single file 100 times from one S3 Bucket to Another Parallel

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, performance-testing

I would like to create a shell script which should be able to copy a single file of size 2GB from one AWS S3 Bucket to Another AWS S3 Bucket 100 times in parallel.

```
#!/bin/bash 
FILES="xxx.csv" 
TABLES="table1 table2 table3 table4 table5" 
SOURCE="s3://SourceBucket" 
TARGET_PREFIX="s3://TargetBucket/" 
echo "Uploading from $SOURCE" 
for 
table in $TABLES 
do 
echo "Table: $table" 
for file in $FILES 
do TARGET="$TARGET_PREFIX/$table/$TARGET_PART" 
echo "Uploading $file to INGEST Bucket" 
aws s3 cp $SOURCE/$file $TARGET --sse "AES256" 
done 
done
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in your script. You need to have the `for` instruction on the same line as the arguments. Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check for syntax errors in bash

Comment: Also, do you have a specific problem with this script ? Does it simply fail to run ? Does it show a wrong output ? Do you have a specific error message ?

Comment: The Script is running fine but it is running in recursive mode and copying the number of files present in the source in a sequential manner to other bucket. I would like to have all files copied in parallel for intance if their is only single file 100 instance of that should start to get copied to destination bucket all together not sequentially

Comment: Do you want to copy the sam file from the same source 100 times to the same target? Or do you want to copy different files?

Comment: unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Edit your Q to show the starting state of your system, and then the final state of your system (related to the copying problem). You don't need to show all 100 copies, just some notation like `file ... file ...` .Don't answer here in comments, update your Q! . Good luck.

Comment: _Why_ are you wishing to do this? Are you actually wanting to measure available bandwidth?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: Yes I am trying to perform Load Testing

Comment: @shellter: the Final state should be 100 copies of same file in Target bucket

Comment: @WalterA: Same File 100 Times to same Target Bucket

Comment: how can you have a 100 copies of the **same** file in the same target directory. You must be renaming them as well. Don't ask us to guess what you want. This is why we ask that you improve your Q to avoid verbal descriptions and illustrate the issue with a "picture" of what you require.

Comment: When you copy once, you are done. Skip the other 99 calls. When you try to copy 100 times, ans dome locking is by AWS, you can have a part of your 100 files fail with a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your goal is to **measure the network performance of a given Amazon EC2 instance**. Rather than writing it yourself, you can take advantage of tools that other people have created.

If you wish to measure the bandwidth **between two Amazon EC2 instances** in the same VPC, you can use `iperf`.

For details, see: [Benchmark Network Throughput Between Amazon EC2 Linux Instances in the Same VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-linux-ec2/)

If you wish to measure the performance **between Amazon EC2 and Amazon S3**, you could use [dvassallo/s3-benchmark: Measure Amazon S3's performance from any location](https://github.com/dvassallo/s3-benchmark).

For a Reddit discussion on this tool, see: [S3 Bandwidth from Every EC2 Instance Type : programming](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/b9f5al/s3_bandwidth_from_every_ec2_instance_type/)